# SQL : Join similar tables (different column order, different field names) into one

Tags: mysql, merge

I have 3 files containing similar information, although each file has its own format, column order, fields name...
I would like to consolidate these 3 tables into one, to be able to perform analysis on the whole table.
I tried first do to that directly by importing the files with SQL Workbench Import Wizard, assigning each field in the source file into the destination table, but that didn't work.
So now, I have imported the 3 tables in full in SQL and want to merge them.

ex.

- Table 1: Date, Name, Amount, Interest Rate
- Table 2: Loan Date, Loan Name, Loan Amount, Interest

Would like to merge into:

- Sourcefile (indicates if data comes from Table 1 or 2),
- Date Field (using Date in Table 1 or Loan Date in Table 2),
- Name Field (using Name in Table 1 or Loan Name in Table 2),
- Amount Field (using Amount or Loan Amount),
- Interest Rate field (using Interest Rate or Interest)

Any guidance on how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UNION` to combine the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CombinedTable AS
SELECT 'Table 1' AS `source file`, date, name, amount, `interest rate`
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table 2', `loan date`, `loan name`, `loan amount`, interest
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry to ask a very basic question : if my column name has 2 words, like "Interest Rate", I get an SQL error saying unknown column Interest. I tried to write Interest Rate (unknow column Interest"), "Interest Rate" (I get these 2 words in the output table, not the value), 'Interest Rate', Interest_Rate', InterestRate, none seem to work. Also when I start typing Interest, MySQL Workbench suggests me the column name so I click on it, doesn't work either.

Comment: Then I have the impression that if one table calls the Interest Rate as such, and the other one calls it Interest, I will end up with 2 columns Interest Rate and Interest, not one that merges both ?

Comment: @cyrilmadrid Use backticks around a name that contains any special characters.

Comment: Your impression is wrong. When you use `UNION`, the column names in the result come from the first subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Insert into table3 (srcTable, Date, Name, Amount, InterestRate)
(Select 'table1' as srcTable, Date, Name, Amount, InterestRate from Table1)
Union
(Select 'table2' as srcTable, LoanDate, LoanName, LoanAmount, Interest from Table2)
```

Where table3 is a new table with the specified fields

Comment: I tried to replicate that but get Error 1064: SQL Error. I wrote: Insert into CombinedLoans (srcTable, Loan #, Loan Name, Loan Amount, Annual Rate)
(Select 'assetzcapital_loanbook' as srcTable, Loan #, Loan Name, Loan Amount, Annual Rate from assetzcapital_loanbook)
Union
(Select 'savingstream_loanbook' as srcTable, Id, AssetDetails, Amount, Interest from savingstream_loanbook)

Comment: I tried to simplify to the max writing : "Insert into combinedloans (LoanID)
Select Loan # from assetzcapital_loanbook
Union
Select Id from savingstream_loanbook" but then I am back to my answer to the previous reply, it doesn't recognize the field name

Comment: You should avoid special characters and spaces in column names. Try again from the beginning without these chars.

Comment: Will do, but I get these files by exporting from a website, and they define the column name.